# How To get video links from a site

Tags: web-scraping, video, video-streaming

How would i go about getting all video links from a site? An example of this is the app Veezie.st, when you put a link in it it will find all tv series/films and give you the links of the episodes or the film itself how is it doing it? i don't need the code just a general idea on how it would work.

Thank to anyone that will respond.

I really have no idea.